# Date-picker doesn't showing

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a problem with my datepicker. When I focus the text field it shows properly, but when I click anywhere else in the screen (to make it dissapear), then if I focus again the text field without previously selecting another element, the datepicker doesn't show.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeDay: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var day = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate();
                var month = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;
                var year = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, day));
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `onClose` function. When you call `$("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getdate()`, you run the possibility of calling `getDate()` on null.

The following should fix the problem, hope it works for you =)

```
$(function () {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      changeDay: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
      onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
          var getdate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
          if(getdate) {
              var day = getdate.getDate();
              var month = getdate.getMonth() + 1;
              var year = getdate.getFullYear();
              $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, day));
          }
       }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** here's the `jsfiddle` if you need a working proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/jcolicchio/fpS2Q/

Comment: That code doesn't work for me... I don't know what's the problem

Comment: The code itself didn't work for me either, I just copied his code and implemented my fix to make it easier for him. Check the jsfiddle I added below for working code. Also if you are using chrome, check the JS console for errors